# Symmetric power of tangent space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there an obvious way to write 
$T_{\mathbb{P}^2}\otimes T_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ and $S^2(T_{\mathbb{P}^2})$?

Comment: The question is not clear at all...

Comment: I am sorry, what exactly are you asking? 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can write explicit resolutions by line bundles ---
$$
0 \to O \to O(1)^6 \to O(2)^9 \to T \otimes T \to 0
$$
and
$$
0 \to O(1)^3 \to O(2)^6 \to S^2T \to 0
$$
respectively.

Comment: Where does the second one come from?

Comment: The second one is the symmetric square of the standard resolution for $T$. In fact, the first splits into the direct sum of the second and of the Koszul complex $0 \to O \to O(1)^3 \to O(2)^3 \to O(3) \to 0$ which can be thought of as a resolution of $\Lambda^2T = O(3)$.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't do the question as I should but this is exactly what I was looking for. It's not exactly what I expected though... Do you have any suggestion of where I can read a little bit about this? 

Comment: You are welcome. About what do you want to read?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to construct a surface that is a cover of $\mathbb{P}^2$ (following the ideas of Casnati) but the vector bundles I want to use have $T(1)$ as components and then I should work with $S^2(T)$ and so on. It would be good if I learned properly how to get the resolutions you showed me.

Comment: Weyman "Cohomology of vector bundles and syzygies" may be what you need.